# Why does changing column width in SizeChanged event of ListView breaks it?

Tags: c#, winforms

[image: gif animation showing the bug]

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace BuggyListView
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private ListView _normalListView;
        private ListView _brokenListView;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ClientSize = new Size(600, 300);

            _normalListView = new ListView()
            {
                View = View.Details,
                Dock = DockStyle.Left,
                Width = 300
            };
            _normalListView.Columns.Add("Normal ListView");

            _brokenListView = new ListView()
            {
                View = View.Details,
                Dock = DockStyle.Right,
                Width = 300
            };
            _brokenListView.Columns.Add("Buggy ListView");

            Controls.Add(_normalListView);
            Controls.Add(_brokenListView);
            
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                _normalListView.Items.Add($"{i} very loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooog line");
                _brokenListView.Items.Add($"{i} very loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooog line");
            }

            _normalListView.Columns[0].Width = _normalListView.ClientRectangle.Width;
            _brokenListView.Columns[0].Width = _brokenListView.ClientRectangle.Width;

            //_normalListView.SizeChanged += _normalListView_SizeChanged;
            _brokenListView.SizeChanged += _brokenListView_SizeChanged;
        }

        private void _normalListView_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _normalListView.Columns[0].Width = _normalListView.ClientRectangle.Width;
        }

        private void _brokenListView_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _brokenListView.Columns[0].Width = _brokenListView.ClientRectangle.Width;
        }
    }
}
```

In case the gif animation on top stops working: run the code above, **slide the scrollbar of the right-side ListView down a bit** (so the first item isn't the "0" item) then resize the window height to see the bug.

I've found a few workarounds such as: use the `SizeChanged` event of the `Form` instead. But I'm kinda curious why it's happening. I tried to print out the `ClientRectangle.Width` but faild to see any abnormal values.